# Java/Android SDK Memory Leak Using inputStream.available()

Tags: java, android, performance

I've written a Java class that has a pool of existing tcp connections and a worker thread that loops over these connections. In the function that checks to see it needs to process information from a peer it makes a call to inputStream.available(). I'm watching the memory tracker and it's constantly rising. When I record allocation there are several hundred android.util.MutableInt objects allocated at

```
at libcore.io.IoBridge.available(IoBridge.java:57)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.available(PlainSocketImpl.java:128)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.available(PlainSocketImpl.java:225)
at myClass
```

The problematic code:

```
void someFunction() {
    (new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    for(int i=0; i<peers.size(); i++) {
                        peer = peers.get(i);
                        peer.doWorkListen();
                        peer.doWorkSend();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }).start();
}

void peer.doWorkListen() {
    if(inputStream.available() > 0) {
        //Read and process input
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the suspect code

Comment: @QuinnRoundy I've added the gist of the problematic code.

Comment: Get rid of the `available()` test and the sleep and use a read thread per connection. This is poor technique.

Comment: @EJP Why is this poor technique? Are there really no situations in which this is advantageous? If each peer were strictly independent I would have gone with the conventional approach but in this case it greatly simplifies the cooperation if they're ran on a single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is not a memory leak but rather the garbage collector not able to keep up with the massive spam of objects you are creating every second.* Eventually, you'll find your application has momentarily large freezes as gc invokes stop-the-world techniques to mass delete unneeded objects.

From your code, I can see that you are trying to poll availability from multiple streams using a single thread. What I think you are creating here is a very rudimentary and inefficient implementation of Java/Android's non-blocking I/O.

Given the stack trace I am also assuming you are working with sockets in this case. Using `ServerSocketChannel` and `SocketChannel` with a `Selector` can give you the functionality you require. An example implementation with **Selector and SocketChannel only** is provided below (if this were server-side code, you should implement `ServerSocketChannel` with the same logic).

```
public class Foo implements Runnable{
    private final Selector selector;
    private volatile boolean run;

    public Foo() throws IOException{
        selector = Selector.open();
        run = true;
    }

    public void registerChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws IOException{
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        // Optionally use a selection key for write as well
        channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        run = false;
        selector.wakeup();
        try{
            selector.close();
        }catch(IOException ignore){}
    }

    public void run(){
        while(run){
            try{
                int readyCount = selector.select();

                // Selector was interrupted or manually woken up
                if(readyCount == 0){
                    // handle appropriately
                }else{
                    Iterator<SelectionKey> iterKeys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                    while(iterKeys.hasNext()){
                        SelectionKey key = iterKeys.next();

                        if(key.isReadable()){
                            SocketChannel chn = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

                            // Process input here
                        }else{
                            // We aren't interested in non-readable channels atm
                        }

                        // Very important
                        iterKeys.remove();
                    }
                }
            }catch(IOException ex) {
                // handle selector exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class `Foo` acts as the runnable to a thread you create and multiplexes `SocketChannel` in an efficient way, **blocking** (as opposed to rapid polling) the sockets until one is available. Not only does this remove the issue of massive object creation it also removes the use of `available()`** which can be unreliable across different platforms. This design pattern also has the added benefit of potentially being faster than your approach with a large number of sockets as it doesn't have to traverse the list of sockets in order.

Check out tutorials on [Selector](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html) and [SocketChannel](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/socketchannel.html) as well as an [alternative example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Network/0070__Java_Network_Non-Blocking_Socket.htm) for a deeper understanding.

---

* I could only trace the implementation of `available()` to `IoBridge.available(fd)` (I have no sources for `IoBridge`) so a memory leak cannot be completely be ruled out, though it's extremely unlikely.

** The implementation to `available()` varies widely and shouldn't be used as an absolute indicator of how much data is available. From what I found, java's `PlainSocketImpl` hard-code returns 0 for sockets. Even if android has a valid `available()` via `IoBridge.available(fd)`, you can sidestep the problem with non-blocking I/O if it turns out to really be a memory leak in libcore.

Comment: It took me awhile to learn the new paradigm and overhaul a lot of my code but I have it working and with reasonable memory usage. Thanks!